# compact framework download file from url

Tags: .net, vb.net, http, windows-mobile

I need to replace WebRequestFactory, what is this doing? Can someone help me make this work?

```
   Public Shared Sub download_file()
        Dim wr As HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequestFactory.Create("http://www.test.com/test.jpg"), HttpWebRequest)
        Dim ws As HttpWebResponse = CType(wr.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
        Dim str As Stream = ws.GetResponseStream()
        Dim inBuf(100000) As Byte
        Dim bytesToRead As Integer = CInt(inBuf.Length)
        Dim bytesRead As Integer = 0
        While bytesToRead > 0
            Dim n As Integer = str.Read(inBuf, bytesRead, bytesToRead)
            If n = 0 Then
                Exit While
            End If
            bytesRead += n
            bytesToRead -= n
        End While
        Dim fstr As New FileStream("test.jpg", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write)
        fstr.Write(inBuf, 0, bytesRead)
        str.Close()
        fstr.Close()
    End Sub 'Main
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the code below:

```
public static void getfile(string url, string filename)
{

    try
    {
        string full_url = url + "/" + filename;

        HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(full_url);
        httpRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

        HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();

        System.IO.Stream dataStream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream();

        // Dim str As Stream = cdsMobileLibrary2.http_download.getfile(filename)

        //10 meg
        byte[] inBuf = new byte[10000001];
        int bytesToRead = Convert.ToInt32(inBuf.Length);
        int bytesRead = 0;
        while (bytesToRead > 0)
        {
           int n = dataStream.Read(inBuf, bytesRead, bytesToRead);
           if (n == 0)
           {
               break; // TODO: might not be correct. Was : Exit While
           }
           bytesRead += n;
           bytesToRead -= n;
        }

        FileStream fstr = new FileStream("\\My Documents\\" + filename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
        fstr.Write(inBuf, 0, bytesRead);
        dataStream.Close();
        fstr.Close();


    }
    catch { }
}
```